# Properties of the trace of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the trace of an endomorphism T of V be the trace of the matrix A of T relative to any choice of basis $v_1 ,... ,v_n$ of V.
>
> $tr_{_{V'}}(STS^{-1})=tr_{_V} T$ where T is an endomorphism of V and S is bijective $L(V,V')$

My attempt so far.  It's confusing since $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $S:V \rightarrow V'$ so $STS^{-1}:V' \rightarrow V \rightarrow V \rightarrow V'$?  I know that this is a basic property for matrices, but I still have trouble wrapping my head around it.
I know we can interchange the summations, and that would probably be useful....

Comment: Remember that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove first that the trace is commutative for two matrices $A$ ($m\times n$) and $B$ ($n \times m$):
$$
\mbox{tr}(AB)=\mbox{tr}(BA).
$$
It suffices to compute the diagonal coefficients by the formulae
$$
(AB)_{i,i}=\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j}B_{j,i}\qquad (BA)_{j,j}=\sum_{i=1}^m B_{j,i}A_{i,j}.
$$
Now sum these to prove the claim.

From here it follows easily that
$$
\mbox{tr}(P^{-1}AP)=\mbox{tr}(APP^{-1})=\mbox{tr}(A)
$$
for every $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and every invertible $n\times n$ matrix $P$.

The fact that the trace of an endomorphism does not depend on the choice of the basis follows.

Indeed if $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis and if $P$ a change of basis matrix, then $P^{-1}AP$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the new basis.

See the paragraph of the matrix of an endomorphism here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

The answer to your question follows from the above as well.

Comment: I've actually proved both of those identities, but I need to show that the trace does not depend on the choice of basis

Comment: Like I said, this follows from the last identity with $P$ and $A$. Can you see why? I've added a few words.